# Are there any difference in these 2 ways to declare array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

```
    Dim a As String()
    Dim b() As String
```

One says that a is a type of string array

Another isn't very clear. Are they completely equivalent?

Why the 2 ways?

I supposed the first way is saying a is a String array instead of just string.

I am not so sure about the reasoning of         Dim b() As String

I give it a try. The result is that b is a String() that points to nothing.

a is an integer whose value is -1

I am confused.

Why?

In functions we declare that a function accepts an array with something like this

```
Protected Overrides Async Function createNormalLimitOrderMultiple(orderList As BasicSimpleOrder()) As Task
```

Here, BasicSimpleOrder() simply tell that orderList is of type BasicSimpleOrder() and not BasicSimpleOrder.

So why doesn't `Dim a As String()` work

Comment: You can specify the array modifier in either the variable or the type, so both your declarations define uninitialized arrays. If you use the `New` keyword with `b`, you have to / can use both, e.g., `Dim b() = New String() {}` . The same applies to parameters of a Function, so you can have `Function F(b() as String)` or `Function F(b as String())`. With properties, you can declare the member as either `SomeProperty() as String` which is a string, not an array, or `SomeProperty as String`. A lot of confusion, just because parentheses can be omitted, for example when calling methods

Comment: I don't know what *`a` is an integer whose value is -1* means and *why doesn't `Dim a As String()` work* refers to. What doesn't work? `a` is an uninitialized array of strings -- If you have doubts, use always the same form when declaring variables, e.g. `Dim a = New String() {}` (only the Type uses parentheses and `{}` clearly defines an empty array). The same goes for properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most situations you could treat them the same, however there are some differences.

Array size: You cannot specify the upper-bounds of an array if you put the parenthesis after the type, otherwise you will receive an error.

```vb
Dim foo As String(1) ' Compilation Error: Array bounds cannot appear in type specifiers.
```

Property Definitions: You cannot define an array if you put the parenthesis after the name of a property. The reason for this is because you can optionally include parenthesis after a property name definition and then optionally include a parameter list inside the parenthesis.

```vb
Public Class MyClass
    Public Property Property1() As String ' not an array
    Public Property Property2 As String() ' this is an array
End Class
```

Here is the documentation on property statements in Visual Basic .NET: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/property-statement

Comment: `Dim foo = New String(2) {}`

Comment: @Jimi - That statement is not the same as `Dim foo As String(1)`, though I get what you're getting at.

Comment: What is the difference between `Dim foo = New String(2) {}` and `Dim foo(2) As String`? You declare an array of 3 null strings in both cases. Declaring a Field, you just cannot use the inferred version, so you need to declare it in full as `Dim foo As String() = New String(2) {}`, so you're actually forced to declare the Type for what it is, without the parentheses' shenanigans

Comment: @Jimi - I'm not saying that it produces a different result. I am saying is that the syntax using the new clause is not the same as the OP's first example.

Comment: But that's declaring the same Type with the same values. What I mean is that, when you declare a Type in this language, better pick a syntax that leaves no space to *interpretation* on what the Type is supposed to be, eliding the parentheses' peekaboo, also when declaring properties -- But the OP's doubt is expressed in *`a` is an integer whose value is `-1`*: did you get what they mean? I do not -- The question is *why doesn't `Dim a As String()` work*: I don't know what that means